# is there any modo to get information about imagine size with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to get the image size related to certain a link.
Using:

```
match="http://www.something.com" 
link in soup.findAll("a",href=str(match))
```

I get

```
<a href="http://www.something.com"><img alt="Immagine" class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-4405" height="263" src="http://www.infographiclov.com/Immagine-500x263.jpg" width="500"/></a>
```

I'm able to get the href but I'd like to get img alt height and width. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for link in soup.findAll("a",href=str(match)):
    target = link.select_one('img')
    print("Height: ",target.attrs['height'])
    print("Width: ",target.attrs['width'])
```

Output:

```
Height:  263
Width:  500
```

Comment: Thank you very much!